# Find period or comma in between nondigits

Tags: regex

I need to find fullstop or comma, but without being surrounded by number.

For example, either `"14,000$"` or `"53.31s"` shouldn't be matched but `"thank you.see you soon!"` or `"hey,what's up?"` should be matched.

`[^0-9],[^0-9]` is not giving me the expected result, because I should only find "fullstop" or "comma" itself without surrounding characters and in this case, I tried:

`\b[,.]\b` outputs only `","` or `"."` but this matches the fullstop or comma regardless of it neighbored by number or letter.

Comment: Please _edit_ your question and rephrase by showing clear examples of what should match and also what should not match.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Also pick a regex flavor/programming language, please. Are lookbehinds supported (etc)? I'd suggest something like `/(?<!\d)[,.](?!\d)/`. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: this might be enough for your situation `[^\d](,|\.)`

Comment: thanks for the comment. my primary text editor is Akelpad. and I don't know what flavor or programming language it uses. I just thought I could just get some insight for what must be done. I tried your regex (?<!\d)[,.](?!\d) and this works like a charm! can I go one step further and find all period or comma that is ONLY surrounded by letter? thanks :)

Comment: thanks for your suggestion Nithin. but it outputs not only comma or period but also the preceding characters.

Comment: Try \D[.,][a-zA-Z]
This matches Basic Latin characters

Comment: Thanks Tony. but it matches comma plus surrounding characters.

Comment: Try (?=\D)[.,](?=[a-zA-Z])

Comment: Tony Upgraded version works wonders :) now I guess I need to concentrate on the use of ?subexpressions. seems very useful

Comment: I agree fully. Unless you are content with simple matches, understanding of lookarounds, atomic groups, etc. is essential to make full use of regex capabilities, many of which are not obvious.

Comment: What about `123,abc` and `abc,123`?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you only want to match a comma or dot when there is a digit both on the left and right.

I'd suggest

```
[.,](?!(?<=\d.)\d)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HFFdzL/1)

**Details**

- `[.,]` - a dot or comma
- `(?!(?<=\d.)\d)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if, immediately on the right, there is

  - `(?<=\d.)` - (this is a negative lookbehind matching) a location immediately preceded with a digit and any one char other than linebreak chars (`.` is enough since it matches the already matches comma or dot, you may repeat `[.,]` if you wish)
  - `\d` - a digit.

Comment: Hard to say because the OP has not yet responded to Toto's question seeking clarification -- though the "in between non-digits" in the title and the `[^0-9],[^0-9]` which they have already tried (which the question seems to suggest works apart from the fact that it matches the surrounding characters) suggests to me that the `,` in `abc,123` or `123,abc` should *not* be matched.

Comment: So I am guessing that they want something like `(?<=\D)[.,](?=\D)`